# Text disappear while FlowDirection set to RightToLeft

Tags: silverlight

Please check the code below. I am working with Silverlight.

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="blue" Width="100" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
<TextBlock x:Name="tb2" Text="abcd" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="20"  Foreground="White"/>
</Canvas>
```

FlowDirection set to RightToLeft in canvas or TextBlock makes the text to disappear..Any idea what is causing this problem. and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

From my short tests it seems `FlowDirection` is available on `Canvas` only because it's part of `UIElement`. But using it on a `Canvas` doesn't really make much sense. A canvas is just that - a canvas on which you can place objects in exact places.

`FlowDirection` works quite well when using inside a `Grid`. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I'd start with rewriting your control to use `Grid` rather than `Canvas`.